# Why is the game telling me there is iron while there is not

Tags: civilization-6

I searched for iron in the research bar and the game indicates me many tiles where supposedly there is iron.

However, as you can see there is not. In particular, the same thing happened on my territory, and I even destroyed what I had built on the tile (a farm) with the hope that I could make an iron mine later. But it didn't work.

Is that a bug?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that, because you're searching for "fer", it's highlighting "ferme" for your farms.

Comment: There should be an iron icon on the tile itself also.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Fer in French means Iron in English. You mean that the game is looking for the closest looking name which would be Ferme? How to tell the research bar I am really looking for the entire name "Fer"?

Comment: @TimmyJim yes I agree. Which is why I don't understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are searching for "Fer", and the game also found "Ferme". This is not a bug, but simply how the search feature works in this game.

Fortunately, you can tell the game to ignore "Ferme", so that it will only find "Fer" instead.

Take the following screenshot for example:
[image: Screenshot of search result for "Stone"]

As you can see, I'm searching for "Stone", but I also found "Stonehenge".

But if I filter "Stonehenge" (see the red marking):
[image: Screenshot of search result for "Stone" with "Stonehenge" removed]

Then the game only searches for "Stone" while ignoring "Stonehenge".

You can do the same with "Fer" and "Ferme".